# 'Who we are' vs 'Whom we are'

Tags: grammaticality, difference, relative-pronouns

[Source:](https://books.google.com/books?id=N6peZkE0Ya4C&pg=PA92&dq=%22who+we+are+is%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ewsoVe2JD4KlsAWI14C4CA&ved=0CDoQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=%22who%20we%20are%20is%22&f=false) *The Conceptual Self in Context* ... by [Ulric Neisser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ulric_Neisser), [David A. Jopling DPhil (Oxon)](http://philosophy.gradstudies.yorku.ca/faculty/#jd2)

> ... The Western philosophical tradition 
>   provides a venerable partial answer to the question of **who we are**: What 
>   characterizes the essence of **who we are** is a locus of consciousness and 
>   rationality  ...
>
> [[I already read this:]](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/who-versus-whom) First, to know whether to use "who" or "whom," we need to talk about the difference between [subjects and objects](http://grammar.quickanddirtytips.com/subject-and-object.aspx) because you use "who" when you are referring to the subject of a clause and "whom" when you are referring to the object of a clause.

My guess: **we** is the subject. In this relative clause, the speaker represents **we** as another OBJECT. Since OBJECTS require 'whom', **whom we are** is right, and **who we are** is wrong.

Yet my guess jars with [the following](http://forum.thefreedictionary.com/postst31804_Another-who-whom-question.aspx). So am I wrong?

> [User 'RuthP' dated 2012 Dec 26:]
>   That is a(n incorrect) hyper-correctness, to which many people are prey. No, because the only verb you have is **to be** (**are**, in this case). **To be** cannot take an object, because it is an identity, so in your sentences, **who** and **we** are the same. Since **we** is the subject, so is **who**.

If apt, please see user 'leonAzul' 's comment, dated 2012 Dec 26 (also in this same thread).

Comment: My best advice is to forget about *whom* entirely. It's obsolescent.

Comment: ***Who** saw her? **He** did* (subject). ***Whom** did he see? He saw **her*** (object). It's *I know **who I** am* and *We know **who we** are*, not *We know **whom we/us** are*. But Dan's advice is sound. Forget about ***whom*** and no-one except a few stick-in-the-mud pedants will criticise you.

Comment: *Whom* is alive and well in the formal written register that Law Area is so interested in.  In particular, it survives directly following a preposition.

Comment: Is he *who* he says he is? In classical grammar-speak,  "is" wants a nominative complement, not a dative or an accusative form.

Comment: What do you mean, "such sentences as above"?  You gave no examples of actual usage, only the indtructional text, in which all the instances of "who" and "whom" were in quote marks, because they were being referred to AS WORDS, not being used in the syntax of the sentence. Did you have some other sentences in mind, that use "who" or "whom", when you wrote "in the sentences above"?

Comment: @BrianHitchcock Sorry for the confusion. I meant 'Who we are' and 'Whom we are' as the clauses (I shouldn't have written 'sentences'); so I've corrected the OP. Better?

Comment: Neither of them is even a clause. It cannot be answered without futher context.  Who are we (and how are we) to infer whom you are talking about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In formal English it is correct to employ the objective form *whom* when *who* represents the **object** of a verb.

In the technical language of grammar the term **object** designates either **a)** the complement of a preposition (a sense which is not in play here) or **b)** the complement of a verb which in some sense receives or suffers the action of the verb.

The verb *BE*, however, does not ascribe an action to the subject, but an identity or quality. There is no **object** with *BE* but a different sort of complement called a **predicate complement**. Because that complement is not an **object** it is not represented by *whom* but by *who*.